# Is there an easy way to determine an HTML element's content category?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

HTML elements belong to [content cagetories](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories). For my task at hand, I need to ensure that I'm not nesting interactive content nodes.

Currently, I can traverse the node's parents to make sure none of them are of the type `<a>, <button>, <details>, <embed>, <iframe>, <keygen>, <label>, <select>, and <textarea>`. All of these elements are part of the "Interactive content" category.

Other types can also be interactive.

- `<audio>`, if the controls attribute is present
- `<img>`, if the usemap attribute is present
- `<input>`, if the type attribute is not in the hidden state
- `<menu>`, if the type attribute is in the toolbar state
- `<object>`, if the usemap attribute is present
- `<video>`, if the controls attribute is present

Additionally, any element with a `tabindex` attribute [is considered interactive](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#interactive-content-0).

These rules are all part of the HTML spec and are well-documented, but kind of a pain to keep track of. Is there an easier way of checking which content categories an element belongs to?

Comment: I don't think there's an automatic way. What are you doing that requires you to know it? It seems like this is mainly something that browser designers need to deal with, not application programmers. The only non-browser applications I can think of that need to know it are HTML validators.

Comment: @Barmar I'm working on a bug in an application that stems from nested `<a>` tags. I may have gone too far down the rabbit hole...

Comment: @JakeParis how so? the OP said "Is there an easy way to..." implying that there is a hard way that they have already tried. And for my own curiosity I would like to see what they have tried. Also another reason why I said that and didn't downvote the question as most people do when they say that.

Comment: @Adjit the hard way that I've already tried is exactly what I described in my post.

Comment: How are you keeping track of the rules from the HTML Spec?

Comment: I'd missed the bit about the tabindex attribute. That's really bad. Curiously the HTML5 validators seem to miss it too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is nothing in the DOM for the classification of elements that way. The classifications have been made in HTML5 spec prose only. There are few *old* classifications that are reflected in the DOM, such as classification of form fields by their type, with the `type` property, and you can indirectly find some classifications according to *rendering* rules in the sense that different elements have different `display` property value in style settings. But all these modern classifications need to be implemented in your code using lists of element names. You can see this from by taking a very close look at DOM definitions in HTML5 and finding out that they don’t cover the classifications.